# Accessing Arduino serial monitor output in PHP via fopen gives me the error of permission denied

Tags: php, serial-port, fopen, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

```
 "Warning: fopen(com3): failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\XAMP\htdocs\Backend\arduino.php on line 4"
```

my code is as follows

```
<?php
    exec("mode COM3 BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 xon=off");

    $fp = fopen("com3", "r"); 
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "Not open";
    } else {
        $string = fgets($fp);
        echo $string;
        fclose($fp); 
    }
?>
```

All the parameters are correct (or so do i think), the port is COM3 the baud is also correct. The rest of the code i dont know just got it off the interent . New to Arduino and PHP integration. Guide me. Thanks

Comment: Please put a better description of what you already tried.

Comment: Try running Xampp with Admin Privileges. Right click on XAMPP and then Run as Admin

Comment: @Nevermore run as admin doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved by using dio_open.

- You have to first download the extension of dio_open form [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/dio).
- Extract the dll file and add it to XAMP\php\ext
- Edit the php.ini file and add your extension there.

The final code looks something like this:

```
<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", "1");
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  exec("mode COM3 BAUD=9600 PARITY=N data=8 stop=1 xon=off");

  $fd =  _open('com3', O_RDWR);

  if (!$fd) {
    echo "Not open";
  } else {
  $string = dio_read($fd,1024);
  echo $string;
  }
  dio_close($fd);
?>
```